# facebook-ios-sdk requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends"

Tags: iphone, facebook

i can't find any basic documentation on this sdk (am i just being stupid or looking in the wrong place?). i can't work out what this method:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result
```

actually returns in the case of a request like this:

```
requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends"
```

or this:

```
requestWithGraphPath:@"me"
```

result seems to be an nsdictionary, but i don't know what to expect in it etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed with following codes

```
 if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
      NSLog(@"count : %d ", [result count]);
      NSArray* resultArray = [result allObjects];

      NSLog(@"count : %d ", [result count]);
      result = [resultArray objectAtIndex:0];

      NSLog(@"count : %d ", [result count]);
      result = [result objectAtIndex:0];

      [self.label setText:[result objectForKey:@"name"]];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question, you were looking for the documentation for the Graph API calls for Facebook. You can find it here :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/