# Facebook wall on view in iOs

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-wall

I'm busy with integrating facebook in my iOs app. On the "news" page of that app I want to show a facebook wall of some facebook account.

I downloaded the sdk and tried to integrate some features but this mainly shows messages of the user itself.

To clarify, I want to use posts on a facebook wall of a certain user as news messages.

Anyone an idea where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show the user's news feed and include what that user's friends are posting. You can use the Graph API for this. There's some good info on the API [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and the method you're specifically looking for is [here](https://graph.facebook.com/me/home).

Comment: Thank for the info. I just want to show a user's newsfeed, without the posts of the friend of that user. I think the graph api can indeed help me with that.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you, [this](https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed) should work for getting a feed for the user and his/her posts.

Comment: See the "Making API Calls" section [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) which gives Graph API examples.

Comment: I've added the FBRequestDelegate to the interface and added this line:[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andDelegate:self] to the implementation file. This worked so far for me. But how do I get that data then?

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628546/facebook-ios-sdk-requestwithgraphpathme-friends) a related answer, but basically you'll get a `NSDictionary` back with all the fields.

Comment: Hey Matt, i'm still struggling with some problems. Can you take a look at the following question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497302/facebookerrdomain-error-10000-when-calling-graph-api-facebook-ios