# facebookErrDomain error 10000 when calling graph api Facebook ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, graph

I'm struggling with the graph api for a few days now and I can't seem to get any further.

In my appdelegate i've placed the following code within the didFinishLaunching

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"cut-app-id-out"];

    NSArray* permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              @"email", @"user_location", @"user_events", @"user_checkins", @"read_stream", nil] retain];

    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];


    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                                   @"test message from stackoverflow", @"message",                             
                                   nil];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

as you can see i'm trying to get the users feed out. I use the following code to place the data into a proper dictionary.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result
{

    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSLog(@"count : %d ", [result count]);
        NSArray* resultArray = [result allObjects];

        NSLog(@"count : %d ", [result count]);
        result = [resultArray objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"count : %d ", [result count]);
        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];

    }
}
```

But the didFailWithError: function gives me the following error:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)

I've place the  FBRequestDelegate in my interface file as following:

```
@interface TabbedCalculationAppDelegate : NSObject 
            <FBRequestDelegate>{
```

Is there something what i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot more needed to handle Facebook responses, especially after authorization. You're not going to be able to make calls against the Facebook API immediately after the `authorize` method. Please see [their sample code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/sample/DemoApp/Classes/DemoAppViewController.m) which shows how to respond to the various events which you will need to do, most importantly the `fbDidLogin` and `fbDidNotLogin` ones. Only once you have a successful login should you access the Graph API.

In addition, it looks like you're trying to post a message with the Graph API. Unfortunately that's not the way to do it and a call like `[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andDelegate:self];` is meant for read-only use. Again, look at the above link for an example of how to use the `publish_stream` permission (their code has a `publishStream` example method).

Comment: Thanks again Matt! I needed this!