# IOS FBConnect with Graph Like a public photo in Facebook

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

```
NSString *graphPath=@"http://graph.facebook.com/#PICTUREOBJECTID#/likes";
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   nil];
[shared requestWithGraphPath:graphPath andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];`
```

I am trying to like a picture and it is giving me this error. 
Thanks in advance.

> err details: Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497302/facebookerrdomain-error-10000-when-calling-graph-api-facebook-ios

Comment: I had implemented others API except this.